# parsing integers from a list to a command line of software

Tags: python, linux, list, cmd

I am inside a loop with a variable y having a list in each iteration.

Input:

```
y= ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Desired output:

```
create pressure at points 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I tried using simple access with

```
print "create pressure at points d% d% d% d% d% d% d%" % ( y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6])
```

gives error:

```
KeyError: 0
```

I want to parse all the value in the list to another software and for that I need to print them. In a specific manner

```
sensorik.cmd('create pressure at points 0 1 2 3 4 5 6')
```

if it can save as y[0] etc. those could be parsed as

```
sensorik.cmd('create pressure at points d% d% d% d% d% d% d% ' % (y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6]))
```

any suggestions?

Comment: y[0] is a string, %d requires an integer. Use y= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `join` the list

```
y= ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
print 'create pressure at points', ' '.join(y)
# create pressure at points 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: this is an example in a loop, in the next step, i may get 4 or 5 values instead of 7 values, in that case I would need to implement it again.. is it possible to couple it somehow with len(y?)

Comment: Slice the list? `y[1:]` would get everything after the first value

Comment: Wait, no, this works fine regardless of how many values are in the list.

Comment: thank it works but what if the entries are tuples? like y= (60, 61, 62, 63, 64).. in this case I am getting the error of TYPE, which is true. It is possible to do it in the same way or I have to convert the list of integers first to the list of strings and then apply the same?

Comment: Use `' '.join(map(str, y))`

Answer (score 2):

Since the result you want is a string, you don't have to parse the integers.

Instead of `d%`, use `%s` (note that the percent has to be first):

```
>>> y= ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
>>> print "create pressure at points %s %s %s %s %s %s %s" % ( y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3], y[4], y[5], y[6])
create pressure at points 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: this is an example in a loop, in the next step, i may get 4 or 5 values instead of 7 values, in that case I would need to implement it again.. is it possible to couple it somehow with len(y?)

Comment: In that case, use cricket_007's answer